# Dynamically add inputs with their own ng-models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-material

I have a need for users to be able to add new account codes to a form, and have the ability to alter each individual code before sending the form to the server. My markup looks like this:

```html
<div id="acodes-wrapper">

<md-content id="acctCodeSection{{$index}}" ng-repeat="amt in acctCodeSegments">
<div class="acct-code-container>
  <md-content>

    <md-input-container>
      <label>FF</label>
      <input ng-model="userInputAcctCodes.ff" class="aCodesInputs" maxlength="2" auto-advance />
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
      <label>XXXX</label>
      <input ng-model="userInputAcctCodes.program" class="aCodesInputs" maxlength="4" auto-advance />
    </md-input-container>

  </md-content>
</div>
</md-content>

</div>

<md-content>
  <md-button ng-click="copyAcctCode()">Add</md-button>
</md-content>
```

The ng-repeat here is tied to an array in the controller, which is iterated via a function:

```js
$scope.acctCodeSegments = [1];
$scope.codeHolder = [];
$scope.userInputAcctCodes = {
  ff: '', program: ''
};

//'Add button functionality'
$scope.copyAcctCode = function(){

  //Add new acct code segment to markup
  let addIndex = $scope.acctCodeSegments.slice(-1)[0]+1;
  $scope.acctCodeSegments.push(addIndex);

  let acData = $scope.userInputAcctCodes;

  //Push current model values to holding array
  $scope.codeHolder.push({ 
    ff: acData.ff, type: acData.program
  };

  //Wipe original model
  $scope.userInputAcctCodes = {
     ff: '', program: ''
  };
};
```

What I'm struggling to come up with is an decent way to make the original markup use the model data that is pushed to the codeHolder array, while the new markup uses the original data model. Basically I need a way to alter the ng-models in each input tag. I could probably do this with Jquery, but that would get really messy and horrible really quick.

I concede that my approach here may not be the best way either, as its about my 5th attempt at refining how it's done :)

Does anyone have any ideas for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change ng-model of your inputs with the following

```
<md-content id="acctCodeSection{{$index}}" ng-repeat="amt in acctCodeSegments">
<div class="acct-code-container>
  <md-content>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>FF</label>
      <input ng-model="amt.ff" class="aCodesInputs" maxlength="2" auto-advance />
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>XXXX</label>
      <input ng-model="amt.program" class="aCodesInputs" maxlength="4" auto-advance />
    </md-input-container>
  </md-content>
</div>
</md-content>
```

it would enable you to alter the ng-models in each input tag. You can easily add a new row by pushing a new item to your acctCodeSegments array.

Comment: Oh wow, that's so simple I can't believe I didn't think of it. I'll give it a go this morning :)

Comment: This is generating an error I haven't seen before: TypeError: Cannot create property 'ff' on number '1'. Seems it doesn't like writing to the model?

Comment: You are getting that error because your acctCodeSegments is a number array, for the above solution to work you need an object array.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Changed the segments array to $scope.acctCodeSegments = [{code: 1}]; and everything is working great! Thanks!